# Not Getting the output at the client side (UDP socket in C)

Tags: c, linux, sockets, network-programming, udp

Here is my code for the server and the client side of the UDP socket.

The issue is, when I am running this in the terminal, the server execution stops as soon as the client reaches the server, but on the client side I did not receive any data.

Client.c

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
    int network_socket;

    network_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);

    struct sockaddr_in server_address;

    server_address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_address.sin_port = htons(9002);
    server_address.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

    sendto(network_socket, 0, 0, MSG_CONFIRM, (const struct sockaddr *) &server_address, sizeof(server_address));
    char server_response[256];
    int len = sizeof(network_socket);
    int = recvfrom(network_socket, &server_response, sizeof(server_response), 0,(struct sockaddr*) &network_socket, (socklen_t*)&len);

    printf("The server sent the data : %s\n", server_response);

    close(network_socket);
    return 0;
}
```

Server.c

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
    char server_message[256] = "you have reached the UDP server";

    int server_socket,client_address;
    server_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM,0);

    struct sockaddr_in server_address;
    server_address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_address.sin_port = htons(9002);
    server_address.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

    bind(server_socket, (struct sockaddr *) &server_address, sizeof(server_address));

    int n,len;
    len = sizeof(client_address);
    n = recvfrom(server_socket, server_message, sizeof(server_message), 0, (struct sockaddr *) &client_address, (socklen_t*)&len);

    sendto(server_socket, server_message, sizeof(server_message), 0, (struct sockaddr *) &client_address, len);
    close(server_socket);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Here are two things I noticed.  First, you are sending a 0 byte message.  If you change this to a non-zero length message does it make a different.  Also, have you monitored the traffic with something like Wireshark?  There may be a firewall issue on the server side where port 9002 is blocked.

Comment: On the client side do you need to specify the IP address of the server?

Comment: regarding: `int = recvfrom(network_socket, &server_response, sizeof(server_response), 0,(struct sockaddr*) &network_socket, (socklen_t*)&len);`   This does not compile!  between `int` and `=` there needs to be a variable name.   also, `recvfrom()` returns a `ssize_t`, not an `int`

Comment: regarding: `int = recvfrom(network_socket, &server_response, sizeof(server_response), 0,(struct sockaddr*) &network_socket, (socklen_t*)&len);` and `   printf( "The server sent the data : %s\n", server_response );`   the function: `recvfrom()` does NOT NUL terminate the data read, so between these two statements must be the statement: `server_response[ <returned value from recvfrom()> ] = '\0';`

Comment: regarding: `server_address.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;`  The `INADDR_ANY` is the string: "0.0.0.0" which cannot be directly assigned.  suggest: `server_address.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl( INADDR_ANY );`

Comment: `SOCK_DGRAM` are not guaranteed to EVER be delivered.   So there is no guarantee that the server, not the client will ever make a 'round trip' communication

Comment: regarding: `len = sizeof(client_address);
    n = recvfrom(server_socket, server_message, sizeof(server_message), 0, (struct sockaddr *) &client_address, (socklen_t*)&len);`  This will transmit  all 256 bytes of the buffer, most of which will contain trash.  This will be a problem for the client as this will leave no room in the client to NUl terminate the received data.   Suggest using `strlen()` rather than `sizeof()` in the server to set how many bytes to transmit

Comment: in the server, this: `server_address.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;` needs to use the server IP address, not `INADDR_ANY`  and remember to use: `htonl()` to convert the address

Comment: when calling: `socket()` or `bind()` or `sendto()`, need to check the returned value to assure the operation was successful and if not successful, inform the user of the details of the problem.  Suggest calling: `perror( "your error message");`  to pass both your error message and the text reason the system thinks the error occurred to `stderr`

Comment: regarding: `int n,len; len = sizeof(client_address); n = recvfrom(server_socket, server_message, sizeof(server_message), 0, (struct sockaddr *) &client_address, (socklen_t*)&len)` 1) the returned type from `sizeof()` is `size_`t, not `int` 2) the returned type from `recvfrom()` is `ssize_t` 3) need to assure the returned value is >0 otherwise, there was an error with `recvfrom()`

Answer (score 1):

```
sendto(network_socket, 0, 0, MSG_CONFIRM, (const struct sockaddr *) &server_address, sizeof(server_address));
```

You aren't sending any data.

```
int = recvfrom(network_socket, &server_response, sizeof(server_response), 0,(struct sockaddr*) &network_socket, (socklen_t*)&len);

printf("The server sent the data : %s\n", server_response);
```

You didn't keep the number of bytes you received, that's what `recvfrom` returns. So you have no idea how much data you received. You then try to print this data through `%s`, which is *only* for C-style strings. You can't use it to print arbitrary data. At a minimum, you have to tell it how much data to print (otherwise, how could it possibly know?) and you threw that information away.

Comment: "*You aren't sending anything*" - in UDP, it is possible to send a datagram containing 0 bytes in its payload. On the receiving end, the return value of `recvfrom()` will be 0.

Answer (score 0):

On both sides, you are not doing any error handling at all.

On the client side, you can't send datagrams to `INADDR_ANY`, you need to send to an actual IP address.  And when calling `recvfrom()`, you are using the `network_socket` file descriptor as a `sockaddr_in` struct to receive the sender's address/port, which is just wrong.

On the server side, you are declaring `client_address` as an `int` when it needs to be a `sockaddr_in` struct instead. And you are using the same `char[]` buffer to receive the client's data that you use to store your server's greeting message, so you are effectively echoing back what the client sends (which is nothing), but you are not taking the size of the client's data into account. And you are misusing `printf()` after `recvfrom()` exits, since the client is not sending a null-terminated string, but `%s` expects one.

Try this instead:

Client.c

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    int network_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    if (network_socket < 0)
    {
        perror("socket() failed");
        return -1;
    }

    struct sockaddr_in server_address;

    bzero(&server_address, sizeof(server_address));
    server_address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_address.sin_port = htons(9002);
    server_address.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("Server IP Address Here"); // or "127.0.0.1" for localhost

    if (sendto(network_socket, 0, 0, MSG_CONFIRM, (struct sockaddr *) &server_address, sizeof(server_address)))
    {
        perror("sendto() failed");
        close(network_socket);
        return -1;
    }

    char server_response[256];

    struct sockaddr_in sender_address;
    socklen_t addrlen = sizeof(sender_address);

    int n = recvfrom(network_socket, server_response, sizeof(server_response), 0, (struct sockaddr*) &sender_address, &addrlen);
    // or, since you are not using the sender's sockaddr_in for anything:
    // int n = recvfrom(network_socket, server_response, sizeof(server_response), 0, NULL, NULL);
    if (n < 0)
    {
        perror("recvfrom() failed");
        close(network_socket);
        return -1;
    }

    printf("The server sent the data : %.*s\n", n, server_response);

    close(network_socket);
    return 0;
}
```

Server.c

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char server_message[] = "you have reached the UDP server";

    int server_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    if (server_socket < 0)
    {
        perror("socket() failed");
        return -1;
    }

    struct sockaddr_in server_address;

    bzero(&server_address, sizeof(server_address));
    server_address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_address.sin_port = htons(9002);
    server_address.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

    if (bind(server_socket, (struct sockaddr *) &server_address, sizeof(server_address)) < 0)
    {
        perror("bind() failed");
        close(server_socket);
        return -1;
    }

    char client_message[256];

    struct sockaddr_in client_address;
    socklen_t addrlen = sizeof(client_address);

    int n = recvfrom(server_socket, client_message, sizeof(client_message), 0, (struct sockaddr *) &client_address, &addrlen);
    if (n < 0)
    {
        perror("recvfrom() failed");
        close(server_socket);
        return -1;
    }

    printf("The client sent the data : %.*s\n", n, client_message);

    if (sendto(server_socket, /*client_message*/server_message, /*n*/strlen(server_message), 0, (struct sockaddr *) &client_address, addrlen) < 0)
    {
        perror("sendto() failed");
        close(server_socket);
        return -1;
    }

    close(server_socket);
    return 0;
}
```